# How can I install Skype on 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, skype, 32-bit

I'm trying to install Skype on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bits.

I have already tried :

- downloading from the Skype website

  But there is only a 64-bit version available.
- I have enabled **Canonical partner** in **Other software** in **Software and Updates** and run

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install skype
  ```

  that returns:

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package skype
  ```
- also tried :

  ```
  sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
  sudo apt-get install skype
  ```

  but I get the same problem...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is your hardware 32-bit? If not, install a 64-bit OS. Some software like Skype no longer releases 32-bit versions and this limitation can only get worse over time.

Comment: the hardware support 64bits, but I need to maintain 32bits for professionals use. I have a dual boot and can use skype on other boot, it was just to make things easier...

Comment: 32-bit software runs on 64-bit OSes. What other reason could be to keep 32-bit? And just to be clear, you use what you want. I'm just trying to help because I'm sure you don't have valid reasons to run 32-bit in 2017, therefore the root problem of this question is a self-inflicted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since July 1 there is no 32bit version of Skype anymore ([source](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/system-requirements/)).

You can use the [webclient](https://web.skype.com/) or you have to upgrade to 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent application, this is the  [Rambox](https://rambox.pro/#home) . It's still supports text text messages and calls but **not** video calls.

Download the  [AppImage](https://getrambox.herokuapp.com/download/ia32?filetype=AppImage) or use the [deb](https://getrambox.herokuapp.com/download/linux_32?filetype=deb) to install rambox.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!
I recommend to edit this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also How do I write a good answer? for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)